# Symfony PHPUnit integration test not able to check full body text

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

My use case is simple: I am sending text emails, i am trying to make integrations tests in order to check the full text body of the message, please note I don't want to check if message contain a string, i am looking for format and structure. No fancy check since it is just text.

The current public API, as in documentation, and as I see in code allows me to check only whether the message contains a string `assertEmailTextBodyContains()`.

I did read: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#write-a-functional-test, from `MailerAssertionsTrait` can only get a `RawMessage`, i tried, but did not get a strait way to wrap it within an `Email`.

What am I missing?

Is there any technical/non technical issue preventing to have such Constraint implemented?

Something like: `assertEmailTextBodySameAs()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of documentation.

After informing my self more, i realise that in my ignorance i was looking for an idiomatic syntax in the `MailerAssertionsTrait` instead what i needed was just to use the `IsIdentical` constraint from phpunit.

```
$this->assertThat($email->getTextBody(), new IsIdentical($expectedText), 'Mail body are not the same');
```

Why such assertion is not built in in trait i did assume it is just to keep it simple allowing others like me to extend later on easily, it is just an speculation though.